# What are the correct permissions for /etc/init.d/ scripts?

Tags: linux, startup, init

What are the correct permissions for /etc/init.d/ scripts and what chmod options sets them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The common set is simply 755 even though only root should be running them.

So:

```
chmod 0755 <file>
```

Comment: Why 0644 to set 755 ... ?

Comment: Indeed, should be chmod 0755 <file>

Comment: Updated, he can change back if he wants :-)

Comment: Why do regular users need to see where all the configs and other system-only stuff is?  I set it all to 0700

Comment: Clearly because I can't type ;-P
As for using 0700, you *can*, I don't see the point, almost all of the scripts on a machine will come from a vendor so it's easy to get a copy if you want.

Comment: This is giving execute permissions to world (what?) and group (ok, sure).  Why would that ever be a good thing, or necessary in this case?

Comment: What about file ownership? Any references to manpages?